# Pandas forward cummax

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

I'd like to find the max possible return in a stock given a series of price data.  Given that you can only sell at future price, I think I need to need to put the maximum future price on each row:

```
def maxf(idx):
    return prc[idx:].bid.max()

prc['MaxF'] = prc.index.map(lambda x: maxf(x))
```

This code does work but it takes much longer than pandas.cummax().  Is there a direct vector way to code this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

forward cummax is a synonym of reverse cummax:

```
prc.bid[::-1].cummax()[::-1]
```

Comment: Minor: this reverses the whole frame even though we're only going to use the bid column.  Maybe move `.bid` to the left?

Answer (score 5):

A `numpy` version of @Boud's answer would be

```
prc.assign(MaxF=np.maximum.accumulate(prc.bid.values[::-1])[::-1])
```

Consider the dataframe `prc`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
prc = pd.DataFrame(dict(bid=np.random.rand(10)))

prc

        bid
0  0.444939
1  0.407554
2  0.460148
3  0.465239
4  0.462691
5  0.016545
6  0.850445
7  0.817744
8  0.777962
9  0.757983
```

Then:

```
prc.assign(MaxF=np.maximum.accumulate(prc.bid.values[::-1])[::-1])

        bid      MaxF
0  0.444939  0.850445
1  0.407554  0.850445
2  0.460148  0.850445
3  0.465239  0.850445
4  0.462691  0.850445
5  0.016545  0.850445
6  0.850445  0.850445
7  0.817744  0.817744
8  0.777962  0.777962
9  0.757983  0.757983
```

---

***timing over small data***

[image]